# UIPasteboard string returning null from Today extension

Tags: ios, ios9, today-extension, uipasteboard

It seems that in iOS 9/Xcode 7 beta 5, I am unable to access

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string];
```

from my Today widget extension as every time no matter the contents, it returns (NULL). I looked through the release notes and I did not see anything regarding this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just tried, and Xcode 7 GM fixes this issue in extensions =^)

Comment: @EmmanuelG. , i'm using Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001) and having same issue as "Isa Ranjha" please look on My Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075125/uipasteboard-doesnt-work-in-ios9-xcode7-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an undocumented bug with iOS 9 beta 5, in particular, the iOS runtime. Same code works with normal app on iOS 9 beta 5, and today widget in iOS 8.x devices.

Comment: Updates: According to new tests in Xcode 7 GM, the bug has been fixed by Apple. So, reading from pasteboard works as before.

Comment: @utogaria nope this is not fix we are testing in xcode7.0.1 still same issue

Comment: @NitinGohel I have just tried on iOS 9.0.2 (Xcode 7.0.1), everything works as expected. Additionally, I also tried on iOS 9.1 beta 4 (Xcode 7.1 beta 3), it also works. I suppose the problem you have might not be caused by the bug mentioned in this post.

Comment: i told you about when app in background and you are copy text from safari and then open you app that you got nil instead of text. thats the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

My app, which is a password manager, needs to check the pasteboard's contents while in background to clear it after a while, so as to limit the users's password exposure.

The main app, while on background, is also getting nil from the `[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string]` call. When it comes back to the foreground, it gets the correct data.

Because of that, I suspect this is a new and undocumented security/privacy feature and that there will be no "fixing".

Comment: That would be unfortunate although no release notes mentioned this change. From what I have heard, this is a bug. But we will see.

Comment: I hope my suspicions are wrong and your sources are right. :-)

Comment: I am getting "<Warning>: Not allowing bundle ID (myapp.bundleid) access to the pasteboard while it's not foreground" in device console. I think in iOS 9 it will not be possible to get pasteboard data in background.

Comment: Same type of app and rationale here.  I'm finding I can *set* the pasteboard from the background, but not read it - the `string` on the pasteboard is always reported as (null) when backgrounded (even if the previous line set its contents).