# iOS 9 UIPasteboard won't work in the background

Tags: background, clipboard, ios9

iOS 9's `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string` will become null when the app is in the background running a background task or Today widget.

Can't we retrieve a clipboard text in the background any more?

Comment: I'm also having this issue except trying to get the [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image is also returning null.
This is making the keyboard extension app pretty useless now. Hoping this is a bug or a solution is found before the real iOS 9 release.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this post about the same issue, people are saying it might be a bug introduced in the Beta 5.
[Pasting Bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885220/uipasteboard-string-returning-null-from-today-extension)

Comment: I am getting "<Warning>: Not allowing bundle ID (myapp.bundleid) access to the pasteboard while it's not foreground" in device console. I think in iOS 9 it will not be possible to get pasteboard data in background.

Comment: Just tried, and Xcode 7 GM fixes this issue in extensions =^)

Comment: Today Widget is ok in 7 GM, but is still unable to do so in a background task.

Comment: Also it returns NIL when you call it from Today widget when device is locked. So I think it is added for security reasons.

Comment: Anyone seen this again recently? I am using iOS 9.2 with XCode 7.2 and seeing this same error message when I try to access the pasteboard from a document provider extension. The app is in the foreground and the device is not locked.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain where do you launch generalPasteboard?.

This is what I would do:

In your **app delegate's applicationdidBecomeActive method** put in this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"appDidBecomeActive" object:nil];
```

Next , in your **current active view controller's init method** subscribe to the notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(returnFromBg)        
                                             name:@"appDidBecomeActive" 
                                             object:nil];

- (void)returnFromBg {
       UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
       yourTextField.text = [appPasteBoard string;
}
```

PS Don't forgot to remove the observer when the view controller is removed:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```