# UIPasteboard doesn't work in iOS9 Xcode7.0

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7, uipasteboard

i want to update my app to make compatible of iOS9.UIPasteboard's methods ware working perfectly till iOS8 but when i run in iOS9 there is no response from UIPasteboard. i mean to say, i'm not getting string or url or images. i read Apple'S Developer Document but can't find something useful.to get string from UIPasteboard i use following method..

```
id data;
        data = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;
        if(!data){
            data = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
            if(!data){
                data = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].URL;
                if(!data){

                }else{
                    NSLog(@"\nLast Copied URL:[%@]",data);
                }
            }else{
                NSLog(@"\nLast Copied Text:[%@]",data);
            }
        }else{
            NSLog(@"\nImage Copied");
        }
```

any Guidance will be appreciated.
**EDIT:**
see screenshot when i copy text from browser
[image]

Comment: so `data` always remains nil?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, please see EDIT ,i added screenshot.

Comment: Do you even know if your UIPasteboard contains data to begin with?  Can you paste what's in it within other apps?

Comment: Sir, when i tried on iOS8 it works like charm but with same code i tried on iOS9 it doesn't give string. i tried after Reseting my iOS9 Simulator and Restarting my Device. but no help.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, and this methods calls only when if the UIPasteboard changeCount is changed.

Comment: also, [is your app a Today widget or is it running in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920597/ios-9-uipasteboard-wont-work-in-the-background)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, Yes, it is running in background perfectly. i'm not using Today widget